# My query for grouping by date isn't working correctly. I'm always getting the last AND next few days, but I only want the upcoming ones

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm trying to group my meetings by date so I can get the meetings from today and the next three workdays. But that's not working very well. I'm always getting the next days **AND** the **last day** but I don't want that.

```
$grouped_meetings = Meeting::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::yesterday()->toDate(), now()->addDays($days_to_add)])->orderBy('date')->get()->groupBy(function ($val){
            return Carbon::parse($val->date)->format('l');
});
```

I thought it works like selecting the dates between yesterday and the day I specify after that in my code. But it's always returning the meetings from **yesterday** too.

I tried changing the `Carbon::yesterday()->toDate()` to `Carbon::now()->toDate()` and even `now()` but then I **miss** the **current** day.

I have absolutely no clue why this is working like that and I don't know how to solve this problem.

**Edit:** the value of date is always a value in the format of **YYYY-MM-DD**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use carbon now, it will include the time. So for example 2019-07-24 12:34:26

if you use carbon yesterday it will be yesterday at 00:00. So for example 2019-07-23 00:00:00

So you need to use Carbon now and set the timestamp to the beginning of the day, i.e. 00:00:00.

Or another way is you could use carbon yesterday and add a day

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My date format is YYYY-MM-DD I don't look for specific time just for the whole day

Comment: That doesn't matter as when you pass in the carbon->toDate() method it will still include the timestamp into the query, the ToDate method is actually the same as ToDateTime.  And 2019-07-24 10:24 is later than 2019-07-24, which will default a timestamp of 00:00:00 for comparison.

Comment: No Problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

```
$grouped_meetings = Meeting::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->toDate(), now()->addDays($days_to_add)])->orderBy('date')->get()->groupBy(function ($val){
            return Carbon::parse($val->date)->format('l');
        });
```

The `startOfDay()` in combination with `Carbon::now()` fixed the problem.